# Export version control info and history from RTC Jazz

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, rtc, jazz

We have a RTC Jazz server running with about 2 years worth of source control commits, which is running the [Jazz versioning system](https://jazz.net/about/about-jazz-products.jsp) (i.e. not backed by a 3rd party source control system but rather the standalone DB install).

We want to move it to a DVCS (Mercurial), and need to export the source control info including all the commit history and the changesets.

How can we migrate this data? If need be, we can migrate it to an intermediary such as subversion or git if its easier (as most of these have mercurial converters/connections).

Is there even a way to get this data out of Jazz?

Comment: Got $50k? Hire someone to write the RTC -> fast-export converter and you'll be set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, this kind of export isn't trivial because it is hard to get back all the revisions in the right order, taking into account merges.

A simpler approach would be to take the latest baselines, import them in the new Mercurial repo, and keep the Jazz server up as a reference if history is needed.